# How to select optgroup

Tags: javascript, html, select, optgroup

Is there a way to select `optgroup`?

It seems to be disabled all the time. I have tried searching for javascript solutions but could not find any good ones.

Comment: What have you tried? Do you have an example of an optgroup disabled, but not the whole select?

Comment: I'm trying to find a way to select `optgroup` it seems it's disabled and cannot select as part of HTML. Is there a way to do this with Javascript?

Comment: Do you have any code which suggests how the optgroup got disabled? What browser are you using? This sounds browser specific

Comment: @JamesMohler it's just not selectable. I think it's normal but I want to select it so I'm not sure if there's any javascript solution?

Comment: Are you trying to select every single item in the optgroup by clicking on the optgroup heading?

Comment: No I want to select optgroup as a value itself. So have theme selectable

Comment: Afzaal Ahmad Zeeshan addresses this concern. In short, it is not a selectable item

Comment: You should edit your *question* to reflect what you really mean, not just explain it in comments. The question should be understandable on its own, without scanning through discussion-like comments.

Comment: The word “select” could mean accessing an element in JavaScript, or referring to it in CSS with a selector, or something else; this seems to be about something else: you want an `optgroup` element to behave like an `option` element. Instead of trying to achieve such a confusion with JavaScript, consider describing what you really wish to achieve and why (in terms of functionality and sample HTML code).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you can have an example here: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_optgroup

Its just more like a tag, to tell about the options below. Or just like a caption.

If you want to select multiple ones then you might use `jQuery` created select. I mean a custom one, or you can use `checkboxes` and merge them in a list as a `select` tag.

There is no other way to select two options from one select element. Each select must have one and only one value.

Other way is to add the value to each option, and then seperate them using `,`. But there is no option to select `optgroup` Its just a way to group the options under it or more like a label to them.

I am getting a warning alert that I am missing a point, do you want to click on the optgroup and select a value under it? I think this might be the condition!

Comment: The `multiple` attribute on a `select` element allows you to select more than one option.

Comment: But he mentioned multiple no where! :( He just said that the tag is disabled.

Comment: Sure, I was merely commenting on _There is no other way to select two options from one select element. Each select must have one and only one value._ ;]

Comment: Yes, because in his case there can be only one value I suggested other things too, like jQuery! :D

Answer (score 1):

A simple

```
document.getElementById
```

should suffice. See the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sSC8M/) I cooked up for you!

```
var optGroup = document.getElementById('myOptGroup')
optGroup.innerHTML = "<option value='saab'>Saab</option>"
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is no way to do this inside the native HTML SELECT element.  There's also no way to style options inside of a SELECT element, so you can't just use options and make some of them look like optgroups.

You'll have to come up with a work around using a combination of A and UL elements.  Here's a basic one using the below HTML:

```
<div>
    Select
    <ul>
        <li class = "group">
            <a href = "#">
                Foods
            </a>
        </li>
        <li class = "choice">
            <a href = "#">
                Hamburer
            </a>
        </li>
        <li class = "choice">
            <a href = "#">
                Hotdog
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/Zvr7Q/)